# How to select top count, sum

Tags: linq

How to I write this in **linq**?

```
//The store with the most occurrence 
SELECT TOP 1 [StoreName], COUNT(*)
FROM [Xpenses]
GROUP BY [StoreName]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

//The store where the user spent the most overall 
SELECT TOP 1 [StoreName], SUM([Price])
FROM [Xpenses]
GROUP BY [StoreName]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that fact. Please see the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
//First create part of your query you can reuse 
var query=Xpenses.GroupBy(x=>x.StoreName);

var MostOccurrence=query.Select(g=>new {Store=g.Key,Count= g.Count()})
                        .OrderByDescending(r=r.Count).FirstOrDefault();

var MostOverall=query.Select(g=>new {Store=g.Key,Sum= g.Sum(f=>f.Price)})
                     .OrderByDescending(r=r.Sum).FirstOrDefault();
```